# Popular plugins for WebStorm

Tags: javascript, plugins, environment-variables, webstorm, environment

Here is also a list of all my plugins for WebStorm.  True, after the last update, I have not yet disconnected or deleted unnecessary ones. But in general, here you can find something useful for yourself.
What do you think is useful and what is outdated?

```
.env files support
Arc Theme Dark
Atom Material Icons
Extra Icons
JS GraphQL
Key Promoter X
MyGruvbox Theme
PostCSS
Rainbow Brackets
String Manipulation
Docker
FTP/SFTP Connectivity (ex. Remote Hosts Access)
HTML Tools
Live Edit
IDE Settings Sync
Settings Repository
JavaScript Debugger
JavaScript Intention Power Pack
Node.js
Node.js Remote Interpreter
Prettier
Markdown
Shell Script
YAML
CSS
Sass
Tailwind CSS
W3C Validators
Pug (ex-Jade)
ChangeReminder
Git
GitHub
Code With Me
Copyright
Diagrams
EditorConfig
File Watchers
Grazie
IDE Features Trainer
IntelliLang
Machine Learning Code Completion
Performance Testing
Project Shared Indexes
Task Management
Terminal
TextMate Bundles
Time Tracking
WebP Support
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say but "which one is better" / "what do you recommend" and similar "personal opinion" question are not the right questions for this site.

Comment: you are probably right, 
maybe anyone needs